# What is causing .BIN files to not be exported?

Tags: pysimplegui

I am trying to have my code convert a .CSV file to a .BIN file after taking input from a user. But unfortunately it is not exporting the file to the selected directory. Attached is the code.

with open('222.xlsx') as vecfile:
vectors = csv.reader(vecfile, delimiter = ',')
for vec in vectors:
if(linecnt < 0):
next
else:
temp_vec = ''
for i in range(0,72):
temp_vec += vec[i]
#print(temp_vec)

```
        temp_vec = temp_vec.translate({ord(x): '0' for x in ['Z', 'X', 'H', 'L']})
        vec_str = temp_vec + ''  #ADD PADDED 0'S TO MAKE OVERALL NUMBER OF VECTORS % 8 = 0
        #print(vec_str)
        #vec_str = vec_str[::-1]
        #print(vec_str)
        byte1 = int(vec_str[7::-1],2) # COMMENT OR UNCOMMENT # OF BYTES REQUIRED FOR BURNIN SETUP
        byte2 = int(vec_str[15:7:-1],2)
        byte3 = int(vec_str[23:15:-1],2)
        byte4 = int(vec_str[31:23:-1],2)
        byte5 = int(vec_str[39:31:-1],2)
        byte6 = int(vec_str[47:39:-1],2)
        byte7 = int(vec_str[55:47:-1],2)
        byte8 = int(vec_str[63:55:-1],2)
        byte9 = int(vec_str[71:63:-1],2)
        byte10 = int(vec_str[79:71:-1],2)
        byte11 = int(vec_str[87:79:-1],2)
        byte12 = int(vec_str[95:87:-1],2)
        byte13 = int(vec_str[103:95:-1],2)
        byte14 = int(vec_str[111:103:-1],2)
        byte15 = int(vec_str[119:111:-1],2)
        byte16 = int(vec_str[127:119:-1],2)
```

Comment: The only portion of this code that deals with files at all is inside a function that you never call anywhere, and there's no sign at all of code to read the CSV file, or write anything to the output files.  We can't really help you to fix code that hasn't been written in the first place.

Comment: Edited with file handling code